# Evaluate a liquid "if" statement based on value of liquid filter

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a custom Liquid filter I use in a Jekyll site,

```
{{ page.url | git_modified }}
```

Which generates the modification date from the git log ([plugin code here](https://github.com/cboettig/labnotebook/blob/4bf8b20420da1efb1c9a94ec7bb12c7c768b68da/_plugins/jekyll-labnotebook-plugins/git_modified.rb)).

Often I may add the additional filter to convert this to a string or XML schema, depending on context, e.g. `{{ page.url | git_modified | date_to_string }}`.  Everything is hunky-dory unless for some reason my `git_modified` filter fails to return a time object for some post.  In that case, I am trying to write a decent fail condition but cannot quite figure this out.

I'd like to just wrap my call in a liquid `if` statement to check if the variable is defined first:

```
{% if defined?( {{ page.url | git_modified }} %}
```

But I don't seem to be able to use Liquid tags (`{{`) inside Liquid block options (`{%`, `%}`).  I thought I could get around this with Liquid `capture`:

```
{% capture page_modified %}{{ page.url | git_modified }}{% endcapture %} 
{% if defined?(page_modified) %} 
{{ page.url | git_modified | date_to_string }}
{% endif %}
```

but said variables do not seem to be available to the `if` statements.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try doing it this way:

```
{% capture page_modified %}
    {{ page.url }}
{% endcapture %}

{% if page_modified %} 
    {{ page.url }}
{% endif %}
```

If `page_modified` isn't defined, its value will be `nil` anyway, so just use the `if` construct as you would in pure Ruby. I tested here with jekyll 1.0.0.beta2 — `jekyll new test`, then created a file with the above code — and it worked. :)